# Retina render in context performance issues

Tags: ios, ipad, core-graphics, retina-display

I have iPad application that needs to capture contents of view 4 times per second and save as image. I use CALayer renderInContext method and everything is ok on iPad2, but the problem is on iPad4. Probably rendering retina resolution causes bad performances. Any ideas how to improve rendering speed? One possible solution is lowering scale factor, however it does not give wanted results. Ideas?

Edit:

```
- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    if (_recording) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size);
        [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
        UIImage* renderedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(writeImageToDisk:) withObject:renderedImage];
    }
    //redraw at the specified framerate
    [self performSelector:@selector(setNeedsDisplay) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.25];
}
```

Comment: Did you actually narrow it down to `renderInContext:` method taking more than 1/4s to complete ?

Comment: @A-Live i`ve edited question with code snippet.

Comment: @IvanAlek A-Live is right. you need to profile your app. Your issue may not be time rendering. Your bottleneck may be conversion, I/O, too many running writer threads or a number of other things. we could tell you 100 things to check or improve, but only a small percentage will make significant improvements. Furthermore, your grabbing should not happen in every `drawRect:` call while recording -- that could result in a flood of writes per second (for several reasons, many beyond your control).